# Save PowerPoint as MP4 in excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite new in VBA and programming, but I did succesfull make a program in VBA that uses the info from my Excel file and puts it onto different slides in a PowerPoint.

When I try to save as PowerPoint, everything works fine:

```
strNewPresPath = "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\powerpoints\test18"
oPPTFile.SaveAs strNewPresPath
```

After executing, I have a new PowerPoint in that folder.

Now I've read to save as a MP4, I'll need to use this:
    oPPTFile.SaveAs strNewPresPath, ppSaveAsMP4

However when executing, I don't get a new file in this folder.
I don't get any error messages, and that's the strange part.

I hope somebody can help me? Thanks in advance!
Laurent

Comment: I think you missed filename. strNewPresPath & "\" & filename

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer. I've added some lines, but the same result:
    Dim filename As String
    filename = "test.mp4"
    oPPTFile.SaveAs strNewPresPath & "\" & filename, ppSaveAsMP4

Comment: I think there is no ppSaveAsMP4 type. sorry..

Comment: Hi!
I tried that because I've found it on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746389.aspx

Comment: my office version  2010 . that is enable after 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem!

theexport to mp4 works, but in my project, the powerpoint and the PowerPoint programm gets closed automatically.

By erasing the code for quiting the programm, it has time to export the video.

Thanks for the help!